# Host .net core app with iis give a database access error

Tags: sql, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a .Net Core 2.0 application that I host in IIS 7.

With IIS Express the application works fine and I'm able to connect to the database successfully. With IIS I get this error:

> Cannot open database `"Books"` requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user `'DOMAINNAME\PCNAME$'`.

My connectionString in `appsettings.production.json` file looks like this :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
 "BooksDatabase": "Server=PCNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Books;user id=iisAccess;password=iisPassword;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
};
```

What am I doing wrong and why does it say that the "login failed for 'DOMAINNAME\PCNAME$'" when I put the credentials `user id=iisAccess;password=iisPassword;` in my JSON file?

Comment: Is your local SQL express database available to your IIS server?

Comment: how can i see and test that ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/lesson-2-connecting-from-another-computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking for Windows Authentication:

```
Trusted_Connection=True
```

Remove this part of the connection string and give it another try.

The reason for the error goes along these lines:

IISExpress runs as a normal process in your logon session. So it runs with your Windows Credentials. When your app is running inside IISExpress it is actually running under your credential, and when you connect to the database using Windows Authentication, is your login that SQL Server will receive.

The full IIS on the other hand runs as a service under a different session and a different user account. There are the application pools that also play a part and run under yet another account. But the main thing is that those default IIS accounts are local accounts, so they have no "visibility" to another computers. Hence when your app tries to connect to SQL Server, SQL "sees" the machine account, which goes by the name DOMAIN\MACHINE$.

Comment: Also, you're `appsettings.production.json` isn't actually `JSON`. It shouldn't end with a `;`.

Comment: Ahhhhhh ! many hours of searching on the Web and at the end it was only that !! All the *&/?*/@ tutorials put Trusted_Connection=True in the ConnectionString. Thanks

Comment: But why IISExpress was able to connect to the database with Trusted_Connection=True ?

Comment: Why every tutorial goes for Trusted_Connection? I don't know but it is easier this way when it works. Except when you go live it might not work, depending on your setup. As much as I like SQL Server Integrated Security, I usually avoid it when doing web apps.

Comment: This just gets the OP connected with his Dev connection string. It's not using the Production connection string as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is not set correctly on the server (i.e. either not set at all or not set to `Production`).

On your server, edit the system environment variables and add one (if it doesn't already exist) with the name `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` and the value `Production`. Also, edit the advanced settings of your app pool in IIS for the application and ensure that the key `Load User Profile` is set to `True`.

Comment: i manage the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the launchSettings.json. By default it's Development. And it looks like when i deploy on IIS, it switch to the Production automaticly

Comment: launchSettings.json is not used by IIS

Comment: Yes make sense.i will need to manage the environment in the Startup.cs. If iisSettings do this, etc..

Comment: No. Not in Startup. Set the environment variable on the server. This is all in the Hosting with IIS docs.

Comment: I'm not the one who will be managing the Prod Server. I'm just testing with my local IIS server right now. To be indepedant from the Server settings, i read that i can override the system environment variables within the .json config file. Thanks for all your explanations, i will read more about this.  By the way, Load User Profile was set to true already

Comment: Well that's something your sysadmin will need to take care of then. It only needs to be done once and should be done for any IIS web server that will be hosting production ASP.NET Core apps.